# webkitgtk how to control resource loading depends on the type of the resource?

Tags: webkit, gtk

**I want to control resource downloading depending on the type of resource like css, script, img, etc.**

I am testing the thing that loads html from loacl and manipulate DOM with WebkitGtk.
I could load html from local file via WebkitGtk.

But as you know, there are resource to download like img, css or script. I don't want to download those at all.
For img and script, I could do that with setting WebKitWebSettings ( of WebkitGtk ).

But there is not a way to block css in WebKitWebSettings.
So I tried to do by hooking "resource-request-starting" signal.

```
static void loadStatusCb(WebKitWebView *web_view, GParamSpec *pspec, void* context);
```

I could block all network requests by hooking. 
But I don't want to block all resource downloading.
I want to block depends on the type ( css, script, img, ... )

For example, if test_file request came from

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/test_file">
```

I would block. Because it is css.

But from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/test_file"></script>
```

I would not block.

I tried to get any information from SoupMessage of WebKitWebRequest. But I couldn't get any information, but not uri.

If you know any way to do that, please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `resource-request-starting` signal accept several parameters, one of those can be very useful for you: a object of `WebKitWebResource` class, that class has the method `webkit_web_resource_get_mime_type`.

You need to follow the `resource-request-starting` signal handler prototype described on the [WebKitGtk+ documentation](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-resource-request-starting):

```
void user_function (WebKitWebView *webView,
                    WebKitWebFrame        *web_frame,
                    WebKitWebResource     *web_resource,
                    WebKitNetworkRequest  *request,
                    ebKitNetworkResponse *response,
                    gpointer user_data)
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer:). I tried But I couldn't get any information from web_resource. No mime_type I could get. I am using webkit 1.6.1. and I called the function like ' webkit_web_resource_get_mime_type(resource)'. Am I doing wrong ??

Comment: I guess fishing isn't a task for all men... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the "mime-type-policy-decision-requested" signal of the WebView.

In the callback, check if the mimetype is undesireable, then set the policy decision to IGNORE, then return TRUE, which means you handled the signal.  I have a python solution at hand:

```
def __mime_type_policy_cb(self, webview, frame, request, mimetype,
                          policy_decision):
    """Handle downloads and PDF files."""
    if mimetype == 'application/pdf':
        self.emit('open-pdf', request.get_uri())
        policy_decision.ignore()
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

As the good man eagleoneraptor said, you need to follow the `resource-request-starting` signal, but I guess you needed a complete solution. The main idea is to get the request before being sent, and set it's uri via `WebKitNetworkRequest.set_uri(str)` to something you desire or to `about:blank`. Here is how it looks like:

```
    def test(web_view, frame, web_resource, request, response):
        print request.get_uri()
        if (YOUR_CONDITION_BASED_ON_URI):
            request.set_uri('about:blank')

    web_view.connect('resource-request-starting', test)
```